# What IP address did an SSH client use to connect to me?

Tags: ssh, ip-address

Note, I don't want to know the address of the SSH client. I know that. But the only answers I find online are to that question.

I have an interface with multiple addresses. A user can SSH to any of them and, of course, get to the same place. I want to determine, in a startup script, which interface is in active use. Unfortunately, that information doesn't seem to be in the process's environment.

If machine 10.10.2.1 initiates an SSH connection to address 10.10.3.11, which is one of my addresses, it's easy to learn that his address is 10.10.2.1. But I want to know that he used 10.10.3.11. I don't see a way to get that.

I do find $SSH_CONNECTION. It shows the calling address and the port numbers at both ends. But for the local side, it shows the address of the machine's name. It doesn't show the address of either the active sub-interface nor the primary interface. For example,

```
  localhost = 192.168.0.1
  eth0 address 192.168.0.1/24
  eth1 address 10.10.1.1/16
  eth1.1 address 10.10.1.11/23
  eth1.2 address 10.10.3.11/23
 from 10.10.2.1, run "ssh 10.10.3.11"
  SSH_CONNECTION = "192.168.0.1 53999 192.168.0.1 22"
```

I want to find 10.10.3.11 somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the question was a mistake. An iptables rule was changing the destination address, confusing SSH. Sorry for the distraction.